# Finding substrings in a string (HTML, Android)

Tags: java, android, html, string

Working with Android, I am trying to make my activity go to this website

http://busvc.blogspot.com/p/about.html

and obtain all the email addresses to be put in a string array.

What I had in mind was to look at the HTML of the page as a String and find all substrings that come before the `@` (email symbol) and after a `>` character.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I realize this won't work completely as the email address esmall is actually separated by HTML formatting from the @binghamton.edu part. This is a new problem. Need answers.

Comment: What have you done? Are you able to download the page? Or you just cannot parse the page?

Comment: Using a regex will be a better choice

Comment: I am able to download the HTML of the page. I just am not sure how to go about getting the individual emails (and nothing else) to be stored in an array. I am not familiar with an email regex or the pattern you described, Juned. I will try looking it up (if you have any quick tutorials handy, please link me)

Comment: Use `java.util.regex` package. If you just want to find all substrings between > and @, `">([^<@]+)@"` with group 1 is enough.

Comment: There is also a predefined `Pattern` for matching an email address using regex available in the Android SDK. See [`Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#EMAIL_ADDRESS), which is available from API Level 8 and onwards, but obviously a copy-paste of the source is all it takes for older platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Using an email regex will be a better idea, use pattern [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) with the following regex(you may correct regex in case any flaws found):

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*
      @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;
```

Hope you should be able to code using this info.

Comment: I've read a bunch of posts saying using regex to parse HTML is a sin and leaves room open for future bugs. What I did was add to the Android XML for the TextView I was putting the parsed HTML a property that automatically transforms it into a clickable link if someone decides they want to click it and go to their email client.